# have you got a py-poppler-qt example?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, poppler

I'm developing an application in PyQt4 that eventually has to open and show PDF files. For this task there is a python library: python-poppler (in various spelling flavours).

The problem is that it is terribly under documented and the only simple working example I found so far uses Python+Gtk+Cairo, while the example with Python+Qt I found uses an older version of the library, and many major changes have occurred ever since, hence it doesn't work anymore.
It's a week I'm trying to use the code in the PyGtk example to hack the code of the PyQt one, but no success so far.

Has anybody got a simple example of a Python-Qt program that opens and shows a PDF file, which might be useful to the community to see how to work with that library?

Thanks a lot.

[Archive with broken pyqt example](http://pyqt4-extrawidgets.googlecode.com/files/pypoppler-qt4-20962-fixed.tar.gz)

[Archive with working PyGtk example](http://launchpad.net/poppler-python/trunk/development/+download/pypoppler-0.12.1.tar.gz)

Comment: I don't get it. You want to build a lib that opens and shows PDF files, and you want an example that... opens and shows PDF files. So you actually want all the work already done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example buried deep within an experimental (unused) branch of an app, here is a link to the specific file containing the code. Don't know if it'll help? All the relevant poppler code is self contained within the PdfViewer class at the bottom of that file.

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~j-corwin/openlp/pdf/annotate/head:/openlp/plugins/presentations/lib/pdfcontroller.py